# Using Router Parameters in URLs with Angular 4 Router

Tags: javascript, angular, angular4-router

How to use trying to use these kind of URLs with `prefix/foo-bar-1123`, `prefix/foo-bar-1123/bazquux-123` with Angular 4 Router? The important bits are the numerical id's which I am trying to capture.

I have tried this, but the result is that I get a all data between // characted captured to single variable called `categorySlug-:categoryId` and `subcategorySlug-:subcategoryId`.

```
const routes = [{
  path: 'prefix/:categorySlug-:categoryId',
  component: MyComponent,
}, {
  path: 'prefix/:categorySlug-:categoryId/:subcategorySlug-:subcategoryId',
  component: MyComponent,
}]

export const MyRoute: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(routes)
```

Ultimately I'd like to end up with these kind of variables:

```
categorySlug=foo-bar
categoryId=1123
subcategorySlug=bazquux
subcategoryId=123
```

Is this something that the Router supports? Is is possible to extend Router to support these?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UrlMatcher which can be used to implement matching and fetch id's from URL. This works at least in Angular 4.4.3.

```
const categoryUrlMatcher = (url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup, route: Route): UrlMatchResult => {
  if (url.length != 2) {
    return null
  }
  if (url[0].path !== 'prefix') {
    return null
  }
  const categoryMatch = url[1].path.match(/(\w+)-(\d+)$/)
  if (categoryMatch) {
    return {
      consumed: url,
      posParams: {
        categorySlug: new UrlSegment(categoryMatch[1], {}),
        categoryId: new UrlSegment(categoryMatch[2], {})
      }}
  }
  return null
}

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    matcher: categoryUrlMatcher,
    component: MyComponent,
  }
]
```